# Close the application if another activity is opened with NFC?

Tags: android, nfc

I am using TAG_DISCOVERED action in my TagActivity and if my application is already open, I want to close it before my TagActivity is opened. However, When my TagActivity is opened with NFC, I added some logic so it navigates to main activity when pressed to back button, however the already opened app is still there and when I close the navigated main app, it agains show me my previously opened app. How can I close the app if I open my TagActivity with nfc?

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.TagActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

            <!--Registering app for receiving NFC's TAG_DISCOVERED intent-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Comment: what You mean with close the application? Do You want to close other apps that not Yours or do You want just to close an activity inside Your app?

Comment: No, not other apps, only I want to close my app(all open activities belong to my app), so when my TagActivity is triggered with TAG_DISCOVERED action, only that TagActivity should be open.

Comment: when my app is not open, it's totally fine when my TagActivity is opened with NFC. However when my app is open and when I tap my Nfc tag to device and it opes my TagActivity but the open app still there so it's like I have two instance of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** I thought the flag solved my problem but apparently I didn't test it properly. The real solution to my problem is to add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to **my activity** in **manifest** file.

I added FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag to my Intent when returning back and that solved my problem.

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK))
```